# Promise then resolving too quick

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to learn promises with js but i'm a bit stuck. My aim is to grab a image source (using replace) during this showing a loader as some image sizes are large. My issue is that it passes the variable correctly but the "promise.then" runs before the src is created.

Below is the code, I need the src value followed by the loader hiding. I understand there are more ways to perform this but as mentioned, my aim here is to understand promises. I also tried adding a setTimeout but again, the promise then resolved it too quickly adding a broken image sign.

```
$(".owlsmaller").on("click", function(){

    $(".loader").show();

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      str = $(this).attr("src").replace(/-800x300/gi, '');
        resolve(str);
    });

    promise
        .then((str) => {
            console.log(str);
            $(".mainThumb").attr("src", str);
            $(".mainThumb").attr("srcset", str);
        })
        .then( () => {
            $(".loader").hide();
        });
  });
```

Comment: You are not attempting to wait for the image to load, you just have a hardcoded timeout so the image may or may not be fetched by then.  What is your question?

Comment: not sure why a promise is being used in that situation. You want to wait for the image to load?

Comment: My goal is to change the src of another image using the str variable from the promise.

Comment: Seems weird to use a promise for altering a string which is not an asynchronous operation.  Code is going to run so fast you are not going to see the loading element.

Comment: @epascarello Isn't the OP trying to wait for the image to be loaded?

Comment: There is no waiting for the loading of the image in that code.

Comment: So what is the actual goal here? Do you want to wait for `. mainThumb` to be fully loaded before the loading element is hidden? I mean right now you read the source, alter it and pass it to the then, which uses it, and then hides the loading element right away. There is no waiting for any images to load.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;** Your promise is resolving immediately *(*1)* because there's no async code running. Your approach should be different.

**A bit more explanation**

You have a misunderstanding of how Promises work. Promises allow you to wait for the resolution of asynchronous code, but placing synchronous code inside a promise's body does NOT make that code asynchronous.

**Edit:** *As per the comment of @juan-mendez , I'll clarify: The code inside the promise body runs as normal (synchronously) and is executed as soon as the promise constructor is invoked. In fact, the function parameter taken by the Promise constructor is named `executor`, and it gets executed right away!. What ends up being delayed is the invocation of whatever function is passed as an argument to the `then` method, or anything chained after that `then` invocation.*

The Promise constructor is meant for you to run some async function (like a get request) that typically provides a callback for you to operate on the results of that call. Then you can invoke `resolve` from within the callback.

The jQuery functions you're invoking `$` and `attr` are synchronous, so there's no need for a promise there. In fact, your placing of the resolve invocation doesn't even care if `$` or `attr` were async because it's placed immediately after, and not inside a callback or something similar (of course, there's no callback available because there's no asynchronicity).

*(*1) Immediately after all synchronous code has finished running.*

Comment: Promises do make code asynchronous. Try `Promise.resolve().then(_ => .console.log("From Promise")); console.log("After Promise")`

Comment: That's true if talking about the `.then` method, but not about the code inside the promise declaration. That gets executed right away. The resolution of the `.then` is what ends in the microtask queue (therefore, delayed until all synchronous code is done).

Answer (score -2):

Your promise needs to wait for the image to load. And you have assign the return value of replace() to the src of the image?

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  $(this).on("load", resolve)
         .on("error", reject)
         .attr("src", (index, attr) => attr.replace(/-800x300/gi, ''));
});
```

Comment: @epascarello I'm assuming `this` is an image, why won't it resolve or reject?

Comment: Well that is still not right after the edit. That is not how jQuery works

Comment: You can't assign a value to the `$(this).attr("src")` expression.

Comment: Yes, sorry, haven't written jQuery in a decade or so :p

Comment: There's chaining and variables to store things in it.

Comment: @Andreas I particularly don't like chaining. I was really just trying to point out that the Promise was't waiting for anything... Not trying to teach them jQuery